# If I use something available only since iOS 10, does it mean I cannot install the app on iOS 9 for example?

Tags: ios, swift

For example, the new container NSPersistentContainer is only available in iOS 10, so if I use this container (set by default with xCode 8), could I only install my app on iOS 10' phones ?

Comment: what you can install on depends on the target ios version in your project settings, but if the code hits an iOS 10 only feature on iOS 9, it will crash, so will need logic to make sure the OS is 10 before using it

Answer (score 2):

No. Your deployment target (in build settings) determines the iOS versions that call install your app. However, you will need to possibly check in your code for iOS version availability:

Example:

```
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
    //do iOS 10 functionality
} else {
    //don't show functionality
}
```

Good discussion on availability checks:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jake. I saw this solution. I understand the interest with something that you show, but for a container using like NSPersistentContainer everywhere in the app and for sure affect the way I have to code, I cannot use it! I just use the ancient way with NSManagedObjectContext.